# C# XNA - I have a Camera looking at a point -- so why do I need a projection matrix as well? Logic Question

Tags: c#, xna, logic

I am curious about why exactly nothing will display without a projection matrix and what exactly the projection matrix is doing. I've scoured MSNDN to no avail, so I thought I'd try asking someone with experience in it's use.

I have a look at point:

```
viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camPos, trackPos, player.getMatrix().Up);
```

...From my understanding of how this works I shouldn't need any supplemental information to make a camera work. I can make everything show up fine using a projection matrix but I really just don't understand **why** it is needed / what exactly it is accomplishing.

Maybe if someone can pass a link or explain it in brief I will be able to better manipulate the property and get some smoother camera work out of it, but overall I don't like using code I don't comprehend fully.

Comment: scratch all that "I can make everything show up fine" part... haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The projection matrix transforms from camera space to 2d.

- World matrix = Object transformation
- Camera matrix = Transforms World to Camera space
- Projection matrix = Transforms Camera space to 2d space

Without Projection you are stuck in 3d, and we dont have 3d monitors (yet).

Easy example: If you have a object centered in object space and apply rotation to world matrix you will rotate object around its own centre.

If you later on rotate the camera, all objects will rotate around the cameras position.

Later on you will need to want to see what you have done, then you apply the projection. It can either use perspective or not. With perspective projection you basically divide the x,y with z, the most trivial perspective projection is probably:

```
x2d = x/z * screenwidth + screenwidth/2;
y2d = y/z * screenheight + screenheight/2;
```

This gives us a "3d feeling" by points further into 3d space being closer middle of screen, think of a classic star field and youll understand. For more information you will need to understand basic linear algebra, and I suggest you start there as you are interested!

Comment: I think the best place to start would be the creation of these 3D monitors

Comment: @Remm yeah, but that will drag the algebra h*ll into our ordinary computer software ;-)

Comment: The real question is that since XNA knows if you're using a camera you're going to output - why wouldn't it have it as an automatic feature... or at least a 'default' placement. The projection is a matrix but you say it can be held properly in 2 floats (which I might add look quite logically correct)

Well, either way now I understand why 3D graphics people are heavy into mathematics as well.

Comment: @Remm in reality you will want to do much more than what i do in my simple example. You will want to correct fov, clipping and have a kind of perspective/3d brought into 2d space to be able to interpolate the texturemapping in fake3d in 2d, etc. The matrix is just a compact form for many math operations. But it will need a book to be described in detail.

Comment: Yes, regrettably my deadlines merely permit me to seek answers to glitches rather than the pursuit of knowledge. A shame. You win this one, stof. I'll be back when I give up trying to make this perspective matrix follow the player properly.

Comment: @Remm you should probably just set the projection matrix in the beginning of your application and let it stay there. There's no need to fiddle around with it unless you want to do more advanced stuff. But in reality, ie under the hood in xna/d3d and more specifically on the graphics unit, all this amazingly clever stuff are done anyways :)